# How to convert .mat file of v 7.3 into excel or csv without matlab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, matlab, csv

I have a matlab file of v7.3 and i want it's data in excel or csv file. Is there any way to do so , any online converter or through python?

I tried with python but for v7.3 only h5py module can be used but it's only creating a dict and not allowing to save to csv or excel properly.

**Edit 1:**

Code i tried

```
import h5py
arrays={}
f=h5py.File('empiricaldata','r')
for k,v in f.items():
    arrays[k]= np.array(v)
```

Error that i got:

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length

pd.DataFrame(arrays).to_csv('convertedfile.csv')
```

Any resources or Reference will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: *only creating a dict and not allowing to save to csv or excel properly* why not?

Comment: because it says array should be of same length..if you know how to do then plz help it's urgent

Comment: Plz provide the code you tried and the error message it's urgent.

Comment: Updated the question with code and error

Comment: The Matlab v7.3 MAT-file format is an HDF5 file, but its internal structure is a somewhat complicated one, not necessarily just a representation of Matlab arrays. And I haven't seen the v7.3 format documented anywhere. You're probably going to have to do a little reverse engineering of its internal structures. I'd start with opening that MAT-file in [HDFView](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/) to see what its internals look like.

Comment: BTW, is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348024/how-to-read-data-from-mat-file-and-export-to-csv-in-python?

Comment: yes and their you can also see the output dict that i got. This tym i asked more specifically with version